# in-app billing v3 unity onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity, unity-game-engine, in-app-billing

Please tell me how to call **onActivityResult** from Unity.
I want to get the purchase results in Unity.

Comment: Depending on how much work you want to spend on it you can also look into using MobiShop for the native integration with the Android SDK, thats a quick solution to get you up and running. https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/63636

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to call onActivityResult form unity. if your purchase is successful you need to send unity message like this one

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("UnityGameObjectName", "MethodToHandlePurchaseOnSuccess", stringToSend);
```

simillarly you can send messages to unity if your purchase is failed

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("UnityGameObjectName", "MethodToHandlePurchaseOnFail", stringToSend);
```